# With pydev,Variables view is empty when debugging

Tags: pydev

Just like this:
[image: variables view empty]

this happened in :

```
ubuntu 16.04+python 2.7.12+pydev 6.4.4.201807281807
```

also in previous pydev versions,even 6.3,and if deleting

workspace/.metadata

to let eclipse to generate new one,at very first several times debugging works fine,the this will happen,and .metadata/log will show

```
ENTRY org.python.pydev.shared_core 1 1 2018-08-13 07:40:01.096
!MESSAGE No existing console history at: /home/alex/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console/history.py
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/alex/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console/history.py (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.load(ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.java:96)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.<init>(ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.java:45)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.<clinit>(ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.java:37)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleHistory.<init>(ScriptConsoleHistory.java:56)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ui.ScriptConsole.<init>(ScriptConsole.java:210)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsole.<init>(PydevConsole.java:84)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevDebugConsole.<init>(PydevDebugConsole.java:29)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.createDebugConsole(PydevConsoleFactory.java:285)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.createDebugConsole(PydevConsoleFactory.java:260)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.console.PromptOverlay.<init>(PromptOverlay.java:77)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.console.PromptOverlayConsolePageParticipant.init(PromptOverlayConsolePageParticipant.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView$3.run(ConsoleView.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView.doCreatePage(ConsoleView.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.createPage(PageBookView.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.partActivated(PageBookView.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView$4.run(ConsoleView.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4577)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

anyone has same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had this problem too... in my case, closing and reopening the `variables` view solved it.

-- not sure what caused it, seems to be a glitch in SWT itself -- the stack trace reported doesn't seem to have anything related to it.